# linkage problems on GCC on Ubuntu 11

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-11.10

I am migrating from Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric), but I have problems when I try compile some applications that works fine on Ubuntu 10.04 no changes.

I installed the sqlite3 and unac libraries, the same that I use on Ubuntu 10.4. I've installed using the following commands:

```
sudo su
apt-get install libunac1-dev
apt-get install sqlite3
apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

but whe I run: gcc -Wall -lsqlite3 -lunac -Werror -O2 -o ILD.out ILD.c

I get the following errors:

```
/tmp/cceRDsMZ.o: In function `removediacritics':
ILD.c:(.text+0x1ae): undefined reference to `unac_string'
/tmp/cceRDsMZ.o: In function `main':
ILD.c:(.text.startup+0x1a): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
ILD.c:(.text.startup+0x6c): undefined reference to `sqlite3_prepare_v2'
ILD.c:(.text.startup+0x80): undefined reference to `sqlite3_step'
ILD.c:(.text.startup+0x98): undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_text'
ILD.c:(.text.startup+0xb0): undefined reference to `sqlite3_step'
ILD.c:(.text.startup+0xc1): undefined reference to `sqlite3_finalize'
ILD.c:(.text.startup+0xcd): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
ILD.c:(.text.startup+0x10c): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
ILD.c:(.text.startup+0x120): undefined reference to `sqlite3_errmsg'
ILD.c:(.text.startup+0x144): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My GCC version: `gcc 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)`

I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Check where the libraries have been installed and pass the path to the compiler. For example with `-L` option.

Comment: Try to move the libraries to the end of the command (`gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -o ILD.out ILD.c -lsqlite3 -lunac`)

Comment: Also, both unac and sqlite3 use pkgconfig.  Why aren't you using `$(pkg-config --cflags sqlite3) $(pkg-config --cflags unac)` during compilation and `$(pkg-config --libs sqlite3) $(pkg-config --libs unac)` during linking (or letting autotools solve everything)?

Comment: @asaelr: Thanks very much. I did it and worked fine now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always pass library options after the c or files.

The fact that you didn't need to before was a non-standard mis-feature.